# Change the text of a NSTextView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I can't find any parameter that seems to be related with the text value showed in a `NSTextView`. I understood that a `NSTextView` uses a complex structure (with `NSLayoutManager` etc...), but I can't find a valid way to modify the current `text` value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The right method is "setString" `[textView setString:@"the string"];`

Comment: This method doesn't exist as of iOS 8 (not sure when it stopped)

Comment: @AndrewSmiley I'm talking about OS X not iOS.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see that tag there!

Answer (score 24):

Setting text on outlet textView Swift Xcode 8.0

```
textView.string = newString
```

Comment: Thank you!  used textview.string? = newstring

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
[textView setString:@"new value"];
```

Comment: I'm speaking about NSTextView not NSTextField.

Comment: but... you point me to the right solution that is probably simpler than what I was trying to do.

Comment: The right method is "setString" `[textView setString:@"the string"];`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set attributed text (formatted text) them try

```
[myTextView setAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)attrString].
```

NSTextView contains a NSTextStorage object that actually holds the text...

Comment: This method is on NSTextStorage now - so, in Swift,  `myTextView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attrString)`

Answer (score 6):

**Objective C** / **Xcode 9**

```
[myTextView setString:@"The string"];
self.myTextView.string = @"My String";
```

**Swift** / **Xcode 9**

```
self.myTextView.setString("MyString")
self.myTextView.string = "My String"
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there - the program is below - this almost works. There are two
outstanding problems:

1) It takes two mouse click to set the correct selection point in the text
   the first always goes to the end of the text. The second to the required
   position

2) A strange error is printed in the shell - Assertion failure in -[LUPresenter animationControllerForTerm:atLocation:options:], /SourceCache/Lookup/Lookup-160/Framework/Classes/LUPresenter.m:

```
  import Cocoa


  class MyAppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

      let window = NSWindow()


      func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

          window.setContentSize(NSSize(width:600, height:200))
          window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |
                             NSMiniaturizableWindowMask |
                             NSResizableWindowMask





          window.opaque = false
          window.center();
          window.title = "My window"

          let ed = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(20, 10, 180, 160))
          ed.font = NSFont(name:"Helvetica Bold", size:20)
          ed.string = "edit me"
          ed.editable = true
          ed.selectable = true

          window.contentView!.addSubview(ed)

          window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
          window.level = 1
      }

      func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
          // Insert code here to tear down your application
      }

  }

  let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
  app.setActivationPolicy(.Regular)

  let obj = MyAppDelegate()

  app.delegate = obj
  app.run()
```

Comment: I think adding `aNotification.object!.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)` to end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` will fix 1). Not sure about 2)