# Displaying text in text view from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

This method found in the `AppDelagate`, loads a text file of my choosing and splits the context of the text file into an array.

Im having trouble displaying the contents of the array in my `NSScrollview *` called `self.textView`.

I am not sure how to update the text view with each member of the array.

```
- (IBAction)loadButton:(id)sender {        
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    if ([panel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL *bookUrl  = [panel URL];
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: bookUrl encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: NULL];
        NSArray *loadedBook = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"#NP#"];
        self.textView.value = loadedBook[0];            
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what the `textView.value` property is. Shouldn't it be `textView.text`?

Comment: textView.text isn't a property that i can assign. Value was the only one that i thought could be close to what i needed.

Comment: Is googling "NSTextView how to change text" hard? This was the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646163/change-the-text-of-a-nstextview-programmatically

Comment: The text view is declared as a property in the appdelegate.h file    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *textView;

Comment: Why on earth would you name an NSScrollView object as `textView`?

Comment: it was called text view when i added it in the interface builder.. and the setString method wasnt avaialble

Comment: I have realised that when i made outlets for the property it connected a scroll view instead of the text view.. :(

Comment: a NSScrollview? really? ok, then my answer wont work, I supposed it was a NSTextView

Comment: You will have to add a text UI element to show the text first, then set the text.

Comment: thanks for the help working now :)

Answer (score 1):

The right method is [setString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/string), which is declared in `NSText`.

your code should be:

```
- (IBAction)loadButton:(id)sender {        
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    if ([panel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL *bookUrl  = [panel URL];
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: bookUrl encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: NULL];
        NSArray *loadedBooks = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"#NP#"];
        [self.textView setString:bookStr];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179008/display-text-using-a-nsscrollview), to see how to add text to a NSScrollView